# Did turtle remove .dx and .dy from python?

Tags: python

I ask this because I get a error when I try to run my code as it states in console that .dx and .dy do not exist. Yes I did import turtle.

Comment: Please show the code along with the error trace

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing `.dx` or `.dy` in the turtle module. What are they supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running a code snippet that caused this error message as well. The reason was ".dx and .dy are **not** standard attributes of turtle objects".

The attributes need to be initialized before using them:

```
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = -2
```

No idea if the snippet was just missing some lines or if other Python version treated this differently, but that made it work.
(I used Python 3.10.10)